# Spark - config file that sets spark.storage.memoryFraction

Tags: apache-spark

I have come to learn that spark.storage.memoryFraction and spark.storage.safteyFraction are multiplied by the executor memory supplied in the sparkcontext.  Also, I have learned that it is desirable to lower the memoryFraction for better performance.

The question is where do I set the spark.storage.memoryFraction?  Is there a config file?

Comment: See this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default file that Spark search for such configurations is `conf/spark-defaults.conf`

If you want to change dir `conf` to a customized position, set `SPARK_CONF_DIR` in `conf/spark-env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to keep it on per job basis instead of updatring spark-defaults.conf
you can create a config file per job, say spark.properties and pass it in spark-submit

> --properties-file /spark.properties

Comment: I take it that the parameters passed in the spark-submit override any other config files.  One follow on question is does the file passed in the spark-submit need to contain all the parameters?  For instance, can I leave out the master in the properties file and the default config file will supply that?

Comment: yes, you can keep common arguments in spark-defaults.conf